# I want to take substring from last . in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a string like the following and I want remove from last `.` to next characters:

```
var str  =  "obj.test.test1";
**i want a function to return this ==== > "obj.test";**
OR 
var str2 = "obj.test1.test2.test3.test4";
**===========> "obj.test1.test2.test3";**

var str2 = "obj.test1.test2.test3.test4.test5";
**===========> "obj.test1.test2.test3.test4";**
```

I know some function like `substr()` but I don't have idea how this possible.

Comment: This is your **15th** question, you should have some idea how SO works now. Don't start your question with a ridiculous greeting. Don't add a "thanks" signoff. *Do* correctly mark up code without extraneous things. Do show what you've tried. *Do* bother to correctly capitalize. (Perfect English is **not** required, but no one gets through the first ESL lesson without learning that the word "I" is always capitalized.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use lastIndexOf function like so:

```js
var str2 = "obj.test1.test2.test3.test4.test5";
var result = str2.substr(0,str2.lastIndexOf('.'));
document.write(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use regex [`/^.*(?=\.[^.]+$)/`](https://regex101.com/r/hN2rH3/1)

```js
function getString(str) {
  return str.match(/^.*(?=\.[^.]+$)/)[0];
}

var str = "obj.test.test1";
var str1 = "obj.test1.test2.test3.test4";
var str2 = "obj.test1.test2.test3.test4.test5";


document.write(getString(str) + '<br>' +
  getString(str1) + '<br>' +
  getString(str2));
```

[Regex explanation](https://regex101.com/r/hN2rH3/1)

[image: Regular expression visualization]

---

Or using **[`substr()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr)**(or **[`substring()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr)**) with **[`lastIndexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf)**

```js
function getString(str) {
  return str.substr(0, str.lastIndexOf('.'));
  // or 
  // return str.substring(0, str.lastIndexOf('.') - 1);
}

var str = "obj.test.test1";
var str1 = "obj.test1.test2.test3.test4";
var str2 = "obj.test1.test2.test3.test4.test5";


document.write(getString(str) + '<br>' +
  getString(str1) + '<br>' +
  getString(str2));
```